# Using Multiprocessing in Uvicorn with multiple workers (thread lock)

Tags: python, multithreading, api, multiprocessing, uvicorn

I am building a API with FastAPI served via uvicorn.
The API has endpoints that make use of python multiprocessing lib.

An endpoint spawns several Processes for a CPU bound tasks to perform them in parrallel.
Here is a high level code logic overview:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Compute:
    
    def single_compute(self, single_comp_data):
        # Computational Task CPU BOUND
        global queue
        queue.put(self.compute(single_comp_data))

    def multi_compute(self, task_ids):
        # Prepare for Compuation
        output = {}
        processes = []
        global queue
        queue = mp.Queue()
        
        # Start Test Objs Computation
        for tid in task_ids:
            # Load  task data here, to make use of object in memory cache
            single_comp_data = self.load_data_from_cache(tid)
            p = mp.Process(target=self.single_compute, args=single_comp_data)
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)

        # Collect Parallel Computation
        for p in processes:
            result = queue.get()
            output[result["tid"]]= result
            p.join()

        return output
```

Here is the simple API code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
import json


app = FastAPI()
#comp holds an in memory cache, thats why its created in global scope
comp = Compute()

@app.get("/compute")
def compute(task_ids):
    result = comp.multi_compute(task_ids)
    return Response(content=json.dumps(result, default=str), media_type="application/json")
```

When run with multiple workers like this:

```
uvicorn compute_api:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 7000 --workers 2
```

I am getting this python error

`TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects`

With only 1 worker process it is fine. The program runs on UNIX/LINUX OS.

Could someone explain to me why the forking of a new process is not possible with multiple uvicorn processes here and why I am running into this tread lock?

In the end what should be achieved is simple:

> uvicorn process that spawns multiple other processes (child processes
> via fork) with memory copy of that uvicorn process. To perform cpu bound task.

Comment: Your `single_comp_data` includes a thread.lock object that can't be pickled.

Comment: @AKX thx for the input. Could you elaborate why this lock is only an issue when running multiple worker processes?

Comment: Because data that moves between processes needs to be pickleable.

Comment: Also, look at multiprocessing.Pool and imap_unordered in particular. Your code reduces to about 5 to 10 lines.

Comment: @AKX I do not wanna use Pooling here, since I do not want to send the complete task data to the process at once, that is why I am using single processes that will we spawned in a loop that replaces the single_comp_data evertime. This way it is faster, since single_comp data is relativly big and slowes down the multi processing if copied all in once like it happens in a pool.

Comment: Maybe you got my last question in the comments wrong, why does the data only move when we have 2 workers instead of 1 worker. I still spawn mulitple child processes, even within 1 worker process

Comment: `Pool` doesn't send "complete task data to the process at once" any more than `p = mp.Process(target=self.single_compute, args=single_comp_data)` does. Anyway, please show your `load_data_from_cache` since the issue here clearly is that there's an unpickleable `thread.lock` in there.

Comment: yes there is, I understand this. My question is then more, why is there only an issue with 2 workers and not with 1 worker, actually?

Comment: Btw. If you apply Pool, then the main process need to get the complete data into RAM first, before sending pieces of this data to the processes, if this is not correct, then please explain how you can use Pool "map" method witouhg loading everything into memory first.

Comment: This could be achieved with "apply" from Pool maybe.

Comment: Can you _please_ show `load_data_from_cache`, so we can figure out why the return value would have a lock in it when running with more than one process? Anyway, I wasn't talking about `.map`, but `.imap` or `.imap_unordered`. Run [this gist](https://gist.github.com/akx/b4412774769e946b4630421ed17a85b8) to see that not all work items need to be generated before work begins.

Comment: @AKX thx for code sample and oultlining the functionality of imap_unordered :+1

Comment: But again: can you show the rest of the `compute` class? Also, have you considered that the "in-memory cache" won't be shared between the N workers you have?

Comment: yes this would be fine, having the in memory cache in every worker process.

Comment: I found it, there was some legacy code in an object, which initialized a redis session.

Comment: Okay, but now the overhead seems to be enormous of copying this data into a new process. This makes me thinking, if the code above performed with only 1 Uvicorn worker actually really runs in parallel or sequentially? Because now the overhead is abot 30x times of run time.  This means that nothing has been copied in the 1 uvivorn worker run, not quite sure what happened.

Comment: Yes, there can be a significant overhead in serializing data from and to subprocesses. The uvicorn worker count doesn't how many `multiprocessing` subprocesses you can spawn.

Comment: Yeah, but I am still wondering what happens in this 1 uvicorn worker process. Also there are child processes spawned. But there you do not have those time consuming serialization cost, when forking some processes. I mean this should be the same behaviour in other processes as well.

Comment: `--workers` doesn't mean threads. It means subprocesses.

Comment: So when I create a new subprocess/child process from within a subprocess, does this mean on UNIX I can not inherit global ressources from the parent process (which is already a subprocess)  instead I need to serilize the data and replicate it?

Comment: So I can not benefit from the zero copy so to say, that a fork brings with it?

Comment: Hold on, I'm writing an answer that covers this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

stems from whatever data you're passing into your subprocess in

```
p = mp.Process(target=self.single_compute, args=single_comp_data)
```

containing an unpickleable object.

All args/kwargs sent to a `multiprocessing` subprocess (be it via Process, or the higher-level methods in `Pool`) must be pickleable, and similarly the return value of the function run must be pickleable so it can be sent back to the parent process.

If you're on UNIX and using the `fork` start method for multiprocessing (which is the default on Linux, but not on macOS), you can also take advantage of copy-on-write memory semantics to avoid the copy "down" to the child processes by making the data available, e.g. via instance state, a global variable, ..., before spawning the subprocess, and having it fetch it by reference, instead of passing the data itself down as an argument.

This example is using `imap_unordered` for performance (the assumption being there's no need to process the ids in order), and would return a dict mapping an input ID to the result it creates.

```
class Compute:
    _cache = {}  # could be an instance variable too but whatever

    def get_data(self, id):
        if id not in self._cache:
            self._cache[id] = get_data_from_somewhere(id)
        return self._cache[id]

    def compute_item(self, id):
        data = self.get_data(id)
        result = 42  # ... do heavy computation here ...
        return (id, result)

    def compute_result(self, ids) -> dict:
        for id in ids:
             self.get_data(id)  # populate in parent process
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
             return dict(p.imap_unordered(self.compute_item, ids))
```

Comment: great, will try this out.

Comment: Okay, this does not work since here again within the Pool dict(p.imap_unordered(self.compute_item, ids))  something gets serialized again.

Comment: The ids do, of course. The idea is you serialise a little and fetch a lot in the subprocess.

Comment: oh yeah okey, this is true.

Comment: unfortunetaly pool does exit uvicorn server process when the context of Pool finishes and gets colelcted by GC.

Comment: No, the pool absolutely doesn't close the parent process. I tried this concept out earlier using uvicorn.

Comment: here is the issue: https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/548

Comment: Well, there's a solution too - call `signal.set_wakeup_fd` in the initializer callback Pool gives you.

Comment: I have put `Pool(initializer=signal.set_wakeup_fd, initargs=([-1]))`  as init callback. Unfortunetaly the code runs again slowly. So again some overhead happens.

Comment: Well, without knowing at all what your code actually does, it's hard to tell why it's being slow.

Comment: It is acutally slower due to signel.set_wakeup_fd